# Handling Long data with BitSet in Java

Tags: java, bitset

I have a large data set with range 0 to Long.MAX_VALUE,
and would like to search for any duplication using BitSet.

While Java BitSet doesn't allow long for its functions.
Is it possible to achieve with BitSet?

```
// incoming data have range 0 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (Long max value)  
// e.g. 1, 3, 5, 1, 2_000_000_000, 2_000_000_000
// expected output: 1, 2_000_000_000, as they appear twice

long[] myData = new long[]{1, 3, 5, 1, 2_000_000_000, 2_000_000_000};
// int[] myData = new int[]{1, 3, 5, 1}; // it working well for int array
BitSet bs = new BitSet();
        
for(int i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
    if(bs.get(myData[i])) {  // fail here as bitset only accept int
        System.out.println("duplicated number: " + myData[i]);
    } else {
        bs.set(myData[i]); // same here
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the problem you have. Provide source code to show your problem, maybe even a [mcve].

Comment: What about `Bitset.valueOf(long[] longs)`?

Comment: @Progman I added a sample to show what I expected to do.

Comment: @julien.giband may you elaborate more on how it works?

Comment: I've responded to the first version of your question, not exactly seeing what you were trying to do. Do you known that Long.MAX_VALUE = 9,223,372,036,854,775,807, which is as many bits to be retained in memory for you BitSet to work with such an index? That would be about a billion GigaBytes. Does your computer have such an amount of RAM?

Comment: @julien.giband seem my understanding to bitset is not correct, i updated the code again

Comment: @brian661 WJS is right. Bitset is roughly an array made of as many booleans as its maximum used index (plus one). So it wouldn't reduce memory usage at all in your case. Checking `bs.get(2_000_000_000)` implies that there are at least as many booleans in your array, consuming that much memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BitSet` could be used by seeing which bits were previously set.  That would then constitute a duplicate value.  However, you can't set a bit position greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE (and it would be infeasible to handle such a large range for longs).  So it would not work for the range you suggested.  And I presume you would still want to record the duplicates.

I would use a `Map<Long,Long>` to do a frequency count.  Then you can just determine the exact count of each value provided.  And locating the next Key of a map is comparable to calculating which internal long value holds the desired bit. So I don't believe performance is a factor here.

If you simply want to eliminate duplicates, then just put them in a `Set<Long>`

Based on your comment, check out this simple test for holding one large value in a BitSet.

```
BitSet bitSet = new BitSet();
bitSet.set(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
long[] backingArray = bitSet.toLongArray();
System.out.printf("Size of backing array = %,d longs.%n",backingArray.length);
```

Prints

```
Size of backing array = 33,554,432 longs.
```

Comment: Map and Set will work, but I am trying to reduce the memory usage, so I came across bitset, or are there any more memory efficient ways?

Comment: `BitSet` requires a `long[]` array to hold the bits.  So for a data set of longs, you would need an array of about size `max_value/64` where `max_value` is the largest value in your set.  For a `Map`, you would only need `count * 2` longs (sans overhead like Map.Entry etc) to hold your values where count is the *number* of items in the data set.  So on average, I would say a map is far more memory efficient for something like this.

Comment: @brian661 you might find my  updated answer interesting.